# Debugging Javascript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following Javascript is in my aspx.cs in visual studio  and I have added a new script to it, but I am not sure whether my script is working properly or not ..so can some one please tell me how to debug the following code....

```
  sb.AppendFormat("function chkQuoteBinderValidUntilDateOverridden_OnClick()", this.chkQuoteBinderValidUntilDateOverridden.ClientID);
            sb.AppendLine("{");
            sb.AppendLine("    var chkQuoteBinderValidUntilDateOverridden = document.getElementById('" + chkQuoteBinderValidUntilDateOverridden.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate = document.getElementById('" + wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_input = document.getElementById('" + wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate.ClientID + "_input');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_container = document.getElementById('" + wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate.ClientID + "_container');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_img = document.getElementById('" + wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate.ClientID + "_img');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var wdcQBValidUntilDate = igdrp_getComboById('" + this.wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var hiddenWDCQBValidUntilDate = document.getElementById('" + this.HiddenWDCQuoteBinderValidUntilDate.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var hiddenQBValidUntilDate = new Date(hiddenWDCQBValidUntilDate.value);");
            sb.AppendLine("    if(chkQuoteBinderValidUntilDateOverridden.checked == true) {");
            sb.AppendLine("        setDateChooserDisabled(wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate,false);");
            sb.AppendLine("        wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_img.setAttribute('src', wdcEnabledImageUrl);");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("    else {");
            sb.AppendLine("    var now = new Date();");
            sb.AppendLine("        setDateChooserDisabled(wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate,true);");
            sb.AppendLine("        wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_img.setAttribute('src', wdcDisabledImageUrl);");
            sb.AppendLine("        if(hiddenQBValidUntilDate) {");            
            sb.AppendLine("             wdcQBValidUntilDate.setValue(hiddenQBValidUntilDate);");
            sb.AppendLine("             if (lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn == null) {");
            sb.AppendLine("                     lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn = document.getElementById('" + lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("             }");
            sb.AppendLine("             dif = ((hiddenQBValidUntilDate - now)/(86400*1000));");
            sb.AppendLine("             dif = (dif - ( dif % 1 )) + 1;");
            sb.AppendLine("             lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.innerText = '(' + dif.toString() + ' days)';");
            sb.AppendLine("         }");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("}");

            sb.AppendLine("function wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_OnBlur(oDateChooser , dummy, oEvent) {");
            sb.AppendLine("    var now = new Date();");
            sb.AppendLine("    var wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate = oDateChooser.getValue();");                       
            sb.AppendLine("    if (lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn == null) {");
            sb.AppendLine("    lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn = document.getElementById('" + lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("    if(wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate != null)  {"); 
            sb.AppendLine("         dif = ((wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate - now)/(86400*1000));");
            sb.AppendLine("         dif = (dif - ( dif % 1 )) + 1;");
            sb.AppendLine("         lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.style.visibility = 'visible';");
            sb.AppendLine("         lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.innerText = '(' + dif.toString() + ' days)';");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("    else {");
            sb.AppendLine("         lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("}");


            sb.AppendLine("function wdcQuoteBinderValidUntilDate_CalendarValueChanged(oCalendar, oDate, oEvent) {");
            sb.AppendLine("    var now = new Date();");
            sb.AppendLine("    if (lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn == null) {");
            sb.AppendLine("        lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn = document.getElementById('" + lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("    dif = ((oDate - now)/(86400*1000));");
            sb.AppendLine("    dif = (dif - ( dif % 1 )) + 1;");
            sb.AppendLine("    lblQuoteBinderExpiresIn.innerText = '(' + dif.toString() + ' days)';");
            sb.AppendLine("}");

            sb.AppendLine("function colInsuredState_OnChange(isNewYork) {");
            sb.AppendLine("    var chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone = document.getElementById('" + chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var lblNewYorkFreeTradeZone = document.getElementById('" + lblNewYorkFreeTradeZone.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var ddlPolicyType = document.getElementById('" + ddlPolicyType.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var txtClassCode = document.getElementById('" + txtClassCode.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var lnkClassCodePrompt = document.getElementById('" + lnkClassCodePrompt.ClientID + "');");
            sb.AppendLine("    var policyTypeId = ddlPolicyType.value;");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("    if(isNewYork) {");
            sb.AppendLine("        chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.style.visibility = 'visible';");
            sb.AppendLine("        chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.checked = false;");
            sb.AppendLine("        lblNewYorkFreeTradeZone.style.visibility = 'visible';");
            sb.AppendLine("        txtClassCode.style.visibility = 'visible';");
            sb.AppendLine("        txtClassCode.disabled = false;");
            sb.AppendLine("        lnkClassCodePrompt.disabled = false;");
            sb.AppendLine("        lnkClassCodePrompt.style.visibility = 'visible';");
            sb.AppendLine("        if(policyTypeId == " + (int)Model.REF.EnumPolicyTypes.ENODPL + " ) {");
            sb.AppendLine("             chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.checked = true;");
            sb.AppendLine("             chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.disabled = true;");
            sb.AppendLine("             }");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("    else {");
            sb.AppendLine("        chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.parentElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
            sb.AppendLine("        chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
            sb.AppendLine("        chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.checked = false;");
            sb.AppendLine("        lblNewYorkFreeTradeZone.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
            sb.AppendLine("        txtClassCode.value = '';");
            sb.AppendLine("        txtClassCode.disabled = true;");
            sb.AppendLine("        txtClassCode.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
            sb.AppendLine("        lnkClassCodePrompt.disabled = true;");
            sb.AppendLine("        lnkClassCodePrompt.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
            sb.AppendLine("    }");
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("}");
```

Comment: If you aren't sure if the script is working properly, how would anyone else know?

Comment: Easy, take your javascript, put it in a JS file, and don't mix and match programming languages.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson ...that was my question is about I never used java script in Visual studio.so I am not sure weather I missed sometng with out my notice .......

Answer (score 5):

1. In Internet Explorer: Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced

   Uncheck "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)"
   Uncheck "Disable script debugging (Other)"
2. Anywhere in your JavaScript script, add this: `debugger;`
3. Run the project and open the webpage using Internet Explorer, when prompted to debug the page click Yes and another instance of VS will open up for debugging:

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Use Firefox and the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plug-in to easily debug your JavaScript.

Comment: The same goes for Chrome, without any plugins.

Comment: ...and for IE using developer tools. Though I prefer Chrome.

Comment: I like Chrome's developer tools, but Firebug is still my preferred JavaScript debugger.

Comment: Everytime this question comes up on SO someone answers with "use Firebug." While Firebug is a great tool (I use it more than I use VS for js debugging) it doesn't address the question at hand.

Comment: The question at hand is "how do I debug this JavaScript". It just so happens that the JS is being written out in the code-behind, but ultimately it will be displayed on the browser, which can then be debugged using Firebug or one of the other browser tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug javascript directly in VS2008 and greater, but you must use Internet Explorer as your default browser for debugging. 
If IE is not currently your default browser, right click on a file in the Solution Explorer, select "Browse with...", choose Internet Explorer and click "Set as default." Now when you start debugging in VS, IE will pop up and breakpoints in javascript will be hit.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a string. You can not debug a string from visual sutdio. string is string :)
You can debug, watch, add breakpoints etc. with below tools on browsers

1. Firefox - Firebug
2. IE - Developer Tools(F12)
3. Chrome - Developer Tools

Comment: When this is written into the browser however, he can debug it using visual studio and IE as jm2 suggested.

Comment: how he can watch chkNewYorkFreeTradeZone.checked value with visual studio? Visual sutdio is not a browser...